# How to troubleshoot error: Edgemart not found: {some SF ID}

Tags: crm-analytics

In CRMA, a dashboard is no longer able to be opened due to the following reason (error):

> Could not open the dashboard because you do not have access to the following datasets:
> {lists the same dataset over and over again}

I went to the dataset it was complaining about and tried to open it, where I get the follow error:

> How to troubleshoot error: Edgemart not found: {some SF ID}

Once I hit this error, I could not Explore the dataset or do much of anything else with it.

I looked for the recipe that created the dataset and I could not find it. There's very little information on the web related to the "Edgemart not found" error, but based on what I have seen others report, perhaps something that glues everything together in CRMA that allows the dashboard to run is missing. In this case, my best guess is it's upset that the recipe was deleted.

What is the likely cause of this error?

If it's because the recipe was deleted, is it possible to rebuild the recipe to output the data the same dataset name to get the dashboard working again?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you no longer have access to the dataset. Verify you have access to the dataset under the dataset Sharing setting. If you do not, you will need to be granted access.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please read [answer]. Asking for clarification is something that should be done in a comment, but you'll need 50 rep to be able to do that. While you work up to that rep score, it's recommended that you contribute to questions that don't need additional clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did not have access to the dataset. I am requesting the owner to grant me access to see if it solves the problem.